# Pref-fill fields on Gravity Forms

Tags: php, gravityforms

I would like to pre-fill a registration form for 2021 school year using last year's info and send out invitations to all parents.
The form all "Allow prefill" turned on for all needed fields. The prefill field name the the 'pf'&the admin name.
I tried sending myself an email with a URL containing the prefill fields=last year's data.
The obvious problem is security since the link contains personal information. So that won't work.

Next I wrote a php function (I initially put the data into an array during development) that will read a csv file on my server that contains the personal information.
I installed it into Gravity forms as a plug-in. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with php functions so I was unable to filter out extraneous calls to the function. It needs to run only for a specific form ID. In addition, I could not understand the part in the Gravity forms documentation regarding the sub function, so it ran every time I clicked on the web site and bombed the site.

My plan was to send an email with an account number and password, and once logged in, the function will run and prefill the fields for that one customer.

I would appreciate help either with this function, or a better way to prefill the fields.
Thanks for your help.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

// for testing
$account = 'B-613048';

$data_array = Array(
Array("pfAccountNumber","B-613001","B-613002","B-613003","B-613004","B-613005","B-613006","B-613007","B-613008","B-613009","B-613010","B-613011","B-613012","B-613013","B-613014","B-613015","B-613016","B-613017","B-613018","B-613019","B-613020","B-613021","B-613022","B-613023","B-613024","B-613025","B-613026","B-613027","B-613028","B-613029","B-613030","B-613031","B-613032","B-613033","B-613034","B-613035","B-613036","B-613037","B-613038","B-613039","B-613040","B-613041","B-613042","B-613043","B-613044","B-613045","B-613046","B-613047","B-613048","B-613049","B-613050","B-613051","B-613052","B-613053","B-613054","B-613055","B-613056","B-613057","B-613058","B-613059","B-613060","B-613061","B-613062","B-613063","B-613064","B-613065","B-613066","B-613067","B-613068","B-613069","B-613070","B-613071","B-613072","B-613073","B-613074","B-613075","B-613076","B-613077","B-613078","B-613079","B-613080"),
Array("pfLastYear","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes"),
Array("pfPG1Prefix","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","","Mr.","Ms.","Ms.","Mr.","Ms.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","Mr.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","","Mrs.","Mrs.","","Ms.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mr.","Mrs.","Mr.","Mrs.","Ms.","Mr.","Mr.","Mr.","Ms.","Ms.","Dr.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mr.","Mrs.","Mrs.","Mrs.","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
);

$num_rows=count($data_array,0);
$num_cols=(count($data_array,1)-$num_rows)/$num_rows;

echo "num_rows= ".$num_rows."</br>";
echo "num_cols= ".$num_cols."</br>";

for ($f = 0; $f < $num_cols;$f++){$fields[$f] = $data_array[0][$f];}

for($c = 0; $c < $num_cols; $c++) {

    if($account == $data_array[0][$c]){
    
        for ($r = 0; $r < $num_rows;$r++){
            $account_data[$r] = $data_array[$r][$c];
            $filter = 'gform_field_value_'.$fields[$r];
            add_filter( $filter, 'populate_function' );
                    function populate_function() {
                return $account_data[$r];
            };
        }
        break;
    };
}

?>
<?php
    function populate_function($g) {
        echo "g= ".$g;
        return $account_data[$g];
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [gravity_form](https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-to-the-theme-file/) function which allows you to pass an array of dynamic population parameter keys with their corresponding values to be populated.

Furthermore, if you did not want to require a login prior to accessing the form you could assign a unique ID to each user which would be defined as a URL parameter to identify and retrieve the required field data.

For example:

1. [www.school.com/signup/?user=unique_complex_user_identier](http://www.school.com/signup/?user=unique_complex_user_identier)
2. Hits a template with a gravity form
3. URL parameter read and decoded to identify corresponding user, else fail.
4. User data passed into form